# How can I web-scraping from a log-in website with Python 2.7?

Tags: python, session, authentication, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to webscraping from a website, where i have to log in first.
The problem is that, there is a "robotprotection" too (so I have to verify that i am not a robot + a recaptcha-security.)

How can I log in to this website?

Here the website code (who are conteins input):

```html
<input type="text" name="user">

<input type="password" name="password">

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdE0w0TAAAAANiqzyAxL1twu4X4ONWrmV0SMv7j" data-type="image"><div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;"><div><iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?k=6LdE0w0TAAAAANiqzyAxL1twu4X4ONWrmV0SMv7j&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cub3B0ZW4uaHU6NDQz&amp;hl=hu&amp;type=image&amp;v=r20170613131236&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=g91tkr9x9ezg" title="recaptcha modul" width="304" height="78" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"></iframe></div><textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none;  display: none; "></textarea></div></div>

<input class="standard" type="submit" value="Belépés">
```

I tried this, but it isn't work.

```js
import requests
from lxml import html
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb
import mechanize
import cookielib

url = 'URL THE WEBSITE'
values = {
          'user': 'XXX',
          'password': 'YYY',
          'recaptcha-token': '03AOPBWq-Ltv5Op-YqU9WsKmE0qtNxr3w-gWwdLMxT4P1ri4j-P1IntWIGT6qRKcouZZr2hmuMPq7HPUL3NUV49gYSIfpnfunppH4tP9EjJO70tUpTaoRO1TkiPvDo8G6fmXaceEu6wMQINpG1-n_Xrp4CllvxcADrLhfmfEMTDmj7TLP-oLLBjFFT3MeMQdcQTndlQ4Kdv9gSTEgQPEl1ljaj1-wVg3zZ9msebL8aLH0Q4yC76AMhsOt4SXpwbliUbcvElWzxvV_uCSXs0jfenPbYYd9vxuy23aOL2kEcISpxsWn_rirDqd66JasBeqtMwTB7XCx_-_hlZlNGluqb4ARXThB7BDq7saKyPRW_TWG2L146qQKl6i9j59bvTE8qdzVMbqhkCboBSP3zTCj-pHkaG2gCrOlRTAVq2IxDNzIP8x0M4hLa8Ho'}

session = requests.Session()

r = session.post(url, data=values)

params = {'Category': 6, 'deltreeid': 6, 'do': 'Delete Tree'}
url = 'URL THE WEBSITE WHERE I WANT FIND THE RELEVANT INFORMATIONS'

result = session.get(url, data=params)

soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "lxml")
print soup
```

Comment: There's a [method](http://scraping.pro/recaptcha-solve-selenium-python/) which can help, but it's chances of success (passing the captcha) is ~30%.

Comment: So i can't write a code which one i can full automate this progress?

Comment: You can, but it's difficult to pass the captcha. Moreover, `selenium` can be of help with logins. You can read its documentation on the Web.