# How can I use a session ID in python for web-scraping dataes?

Tags: python, database, web-scraping, automation, recaptcha

I want to webscraping from a website, where i have to log in first. The problem is that, there is a "robotprotection" too (so I have to verify that i am not a robot + a recaptcha-security.), but it's chances of success (passing the captcha) is ~30% and this is horrible for me.

There is another possibility maybe which one i am log in with my browser (for example chrome or firefox), and after im going to use this session ID in my python script to webscraping dataes automatically?

So, more simplier: I want to webscraping tables from a website, so i have to log in first. This 30% succes rate is not enough good for me, so i hope there is another possibilty : log in manually, and after use this session in python?!
After that, there is a textbox in this page, where i want to write what i want to search, and after it is navigate to the page, where i'll found the table and dataes.

Any ideas, or it is possible?

(now i have only a script which one i have to download the html code to this datapage, and after change some name in the code manually..it is a very big waste time, i hope i can automate it more.) - Python 2.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I web-scraping from a log-in website with Python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44714335/how-can-i-web-scraping-from-a-log-in-website-with-python-2-7)

Comment: If you can read, you can check the difference between these 2 questions!